# Registry of templated types in C#

Tags: c#, templates, generics, stream, registry

I have an interface IDataStream and different implementations of it (i.E. `DataStream<T>`).

I need to make a class DataStreamManager which has a registry functionality (`Find(Key)`) for all DataStreams cuttently available (meaning, the registry should contain refs to `DataStream<int>`, `DataStream<SomeObject>`...), and the DataStreamManager must be singleton.

Does anyone have an idea how to make such a registry in C#?

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>` for this purposes:

Te question is what would be a Key to identify a concrete data stream?

```
public sealed class DataStreamManager
{

  var dataStreamsMap = new Dictionary<Type, IDataStream>
    {
        { typeof(int), new DataStream<int>() }
    }

  public IDataStream Get<T>()
  {
    IDataStream dataStream = null;
    Type key = typeof(T);
    if (dataStreamsMap.Contains(key))
    {
       dataStream = dataStreamsMap[key];
    }

    return dataStream;
  }
}
```

And then use it:

```
var manager = new DataStreamManager();
var dataStream = manager.Get<int>();
```